# nestjs: How to throw an AuthenticationError when I use GraphQL

Tags: nestjs

I write the `GqlAuthGuard` module, but it always throw an `UnauthorizedException` when JWT expired or illegal. It will lead to an error in stacktrace.

I want to throw `AuthenticationError`(from apollo-server-express).

How can I do it?

```html
import { Injectable, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql'

@Injectable()
export class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  public getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context)
    return ctx.getContext().req
  }
}
```

[GraphQL Authorization Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJmUC.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `canActivate` method from the `super` class (`AuthGuard('jwt')`), and from there you can find if the `super.canActivate(req)` returns a `true` or `false` by saving the result to a variable. If false, you can throw your own error there instead of the `UnauthorizedException` that Nest throws.

```js
import { Injectable, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql'

@Injectable()
export class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {

  public async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const result = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
    if (!result) {
      throw new AuthenticationError('Your Message Here');
    }
    return result;
  }

  public getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context)
    return ctx.getContext().req
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to modify a bit the solution proposed by Jay McDoniel:

```js
import { Injectable, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthenticationError } from 'apollo-server-express';

@Injectable()
export class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      return (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new AuthenticationError('You are not logged-in.');
    }
  }

  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req;
  }
}
```